# jqueryui autocomplete with external data in Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, google-apps-script, autocomplete

I'm trying to query an external JSON/JSONP API from within a Google Sheets sidebar, and use it to populate a jqueryui autocomplete widget in the sidebar.

The [demo code from the jqueryui documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) doesn't work within the sidebar. The loading spinner spins, but the list never populates. I presume this is a security limitation of the GAS sandbox.

My next thought was to do the JSON query on the server side, and call the server-side request from the autocomplete box. Here's my server-side code:

```
function getNames(name) {
  var base = "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?q="
  var url = base + name
  return apiQuery(url);
}

function apiQuery(url) {
  var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  return data;
}
```

And in my `<script>`:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sponsorsearch" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var results = google.script.run.getNames(request.term); 
        response(results);
      },
      minLength: 3,
      delay:500
       });
});
```

The relevant bit of HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li><label><input id="sponsorsearch"><span class="small">City name</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

`var results = google.script.run.getNames(request.term);`  won't work. You need to run something similar to:

```
function getData(){
google.script.withFailureHandler('getNamesReturn').run.getNames(request.term);
};

function getNamesReturn(results){
//results is the the return data from getNames; 
Add the jQuery autocomplete code here
};
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of -- unless I'm mistaken, I'd have to call getData() on page load, which means it would have to retrieve the entire database of possible names. (The actual database I'm querying is all current and former members of Congress, so 12,000 names.)


Or is there a way to only call getData once the user's started typing in the autocomplete input?

Comment: (I may be answering my own question here, but I suspect the way to go is to not use the JQueryUI widget, but a homegrown autocomplete.)

Comment: It would be best to get the names during the onLoad function.  If you do it when the text field is activated, it will take a few seconds to even get the data to auto-complete.  I recently used the jQuery method to pull a users contacts, and I was happy with the performance.